# Move QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, onmousemove

How is it possible to move a QGraphicsscene inside a View?

I have a Scene filling the entire View. The Scene is containing one (will be more later) Item (QImage for now), which is updated every few seconds.

My goal is to move the content of the item with mouseMoveEvent. While the item is beeing updated (lasts a few seconds) i want to move the whole Scene and reset the movement after the item is fully updated.

For now I tried overriding the mouseMoveEvent of QGraphicsScene and emit a signal to PPI-Class containintg the QGraphicsScene Objet. The onMouseMoveEvent-slot then tries to set the sceneRect. But this does not work, I get a StackOverflow-Exception.

How can i get this to work? Thank you!

main.cpp

```
#include "ppi.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PPI w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

ppi.ui (just added a graphicsview with size of 1024x1024 and name gVPPI to the mainwindow)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>PPIClass</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="PPIClass">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1079</width>
    <height>1113</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>PPI</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="gVPPI">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>1024</width>
      <height>1024</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1079</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="ppi.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

ppi.h

```
#ifndef PPI_H
#define PPI_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_ppi.h"
#include "ppiscene.h"

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QDebug>

class PPI : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PPI(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~PPI();

private:
    Ui::PPIClass ui;
    PPIScene* ppiScene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *videoPixmap;

    QImage newImage();

    bool moveReset;

    QPointF moveCoordinates;
    QPointF startMoveCoordinates;

protected slots:
    void onMouseMoved(QPointF coordinates, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

#endif // PPI_H
```

ppi.cpp

```
#include "ppi.h"


PPI::PPI(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ppiScene = new PPIScene(this);
    ppiScene->setSceneRect(0,0,1024,1024);
    ui.gVPPI->setScene(ppiScene);
    ui.gVPPI->setMouseTracking(true);

    videoPixmap = ppiScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(newImage()));

        startMoveCoordinates = QPointF(0,0);

    connect(ppiScene, SIGNAL(mouseMoved(QPointF, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(onMouseMoved(QPointF, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)));
}

PPI::~PPI()
{

}

void PPI::onMouseMoved(QPointF coordinates, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    //move view
    if(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
        moveCoordinates = coordinates;
        //ui.gVPPI->translate(moveCoordinates.x() - startMoveCoordinates.x(), moveCoordinates.y() - startMoveCoordinates.y());
        ppiScene->setSceneRect(moveCoordinates.x() - startMoveCoordinates.x(), moveCoordinates.y() - startMoveCoordinates.y(), 1024, 1024);
        qDebug() << coordinates;
        qDebug() << "dx" << moveCoordinates.x() - startMoveCoordinates.x();
        qDebug() << "dy" << moveCoordinates.y() - startMoveCoordinates.y();
        qDebug() << "";
    }
}

QImage PPI::newImage() {

    QImage image = QImage(1024, 1024, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
  image.setColorCount(256);

  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    image.setColor(i, qRgb(i, 0, 0));
  image.fill(200);
  return image;
}
```

ppiscene.h

```
#ifndef PPISCENE_H
#define PPISCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class PPIScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    PPIScene(QObject *parent);
    ~PPIScene();
    QPointF mouseCoordinates;

private:

protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

signals:
    void mouseMoved(QPointF coordinates, QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);

};

#endif // PPISCENE_H
```

ppiscene.cpp

```
#include "ppiscene.h"

PPIScene::PPIScene(QObject *parent)
    : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{

}

PPIScene::~PPIScene()
{

}

void PPIScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    mouseCoordinates = event->scenePos();
    emit mouseMoved(mouseCoordinates, event);
    QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: You're rather confused as to what a Scene is. The QGraphicsScene is like a world with items in it (QGraphicsItems). A QGraphicsView is akin to a window looking out into that world. Therefore, the concept of 'moving the scene' is wrong. You define your scene extents, create a view to look at an area (either all or just a part of it) and fill the scene with items. You can then move the items, or the view, not the scene.

Comment: So I have to move every single item in the Scene? This sounds pretty slow with a lot of items... Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm not quit sure what you're trying to do, but as the view is a window, you can move the QGraphicsView, simply using its [translate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#translate) function

Comment: This gives me the same StackOverflow-Exception.
I am getting signals in polar coordinates via UDP to draw something like a map. I am saving the current viewable signals into a QImage, which is updated every few seconds. Now when I zoom into the QImage (the QImage will be recalculated with the zoomfactor), I want to move at the outside of the map with mouseMoveEvent. Since updating the map will take a few seconds I want to temporary move the scene (?) in the view till it is recalculated.

Comment: My guess would be that setting the scene rect in onMouseMove is a problem here, but you really need to update your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I updated my question with MCVE This code just create a 1024x1024 red QImage, which should be able to move.

Comment: You're calling setSceneRect in onMouseMove - this is not what you want to be doing.

Comment: Then, what do I want to use, to move everything? (Without moving item by item?)

Comment: As I said previously, you move the view, not the scene.

Comment: Which function do I need to use for that?

Comment: Read the 3rd comment!

Comment: I tried that already (see commented line in PPI::onMouseMoved) but that gives me a stackoverflow exception, too.